# How do I automatically enable desktop sharing on startup

Tags: screen, sharing, remote

Desktop sharing works just fine when a user is logged in, but I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as a media server and I want desktop sharing launched automatically. Is there a way to do this without automatically logging into the desktop? Much thanks!

Comment: without login , i think not possible !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the VNC server that comes with Ubuntu is not designed for that. There are many other solutions though. I would probably recommend X2Go or FreeNX, but there are also VNC servers that allows you to do this, such as X11VNC.