# Enable Ubuntu's "Screen sharing" features on startup?

Tags: vnc

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169482/how-do-i-automatically-enable-desktop-sharing-on-startup) was asked 9 years ago, but I'm wondering now if anything has changed since. Basically, trying to get VNC working with third-party apps (e.g. tightvncserver) has turned into an unnecessarily long task and confusion with configuration files, etc. However, the built in screen sharing feature for Ubuntu works absolutely flawlessly and doesn't require changing a single configuration file, very simple and easy.

However, this only works if the user is already logged into the Ubuntu system. Is there a way to "auto enable" this on boot now? Hoping there's a solution out there that's very simple rather than needing to install a bunch of dependencies, changing config files, etc.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question. I use xrdp wh which has the opposite problem. One must be logged out locally to login remotely. Anydesk is another closed source option like TeamViewer, but it does not work if another user is sitting at the remote computer.

Comment: To be clear, AnyDesk works if configured to do so irrespective of if you are logged in or not. It does not work if another user is locally using the remote computer. Then AnyDesk will ask that user for permission to share that user's desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have found another way around, but i have found this: [22.04 - Remote Desktop Sharing authentication password changes every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403943/22-04-remote-desktop-sharing-authentication-password-changes-every-reboot)

It worked for me, but do note it will make it so that none of your passwords are encrypted anymore.
Hope it this helps :)