# Gnome remote desktop password wont save

Tags: password, rdp

So, I've tried googling and posting on reddit to no avail.

I run Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and I'm having issues with the built in RDP (gnome remote desktop).

The problem is that the set password resets on reboot, and leaves that field blank within the settings... This subsequently prevents any and all connection attempts from going through as it just results in an "Internal error" prompt on windows.

I found a thread on here in which there are two answers. One has to do with removing the user password, doesn't work since I can't leave the field blank as described, and the other has to do with autologin (doesn't work either).

Is there some easy solution like finding the resonsible configuration file somewhere and setting the password from within there?

I'm open to suggestions.

Edit: here's the link to the thread that I referred to ([22.04 - Remote Desktop Sharing authentication password changes every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1403943/1004020))

Comment: Is autologin enabled in your computer? If so, disable it. Add links to the question you refer to by [editing your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1502895/edit). Does not work is not specific. Add errors.

Comment: Done. And no, I did not have autologin on prior to making this post. But I now do, and I've also disabled the keyring (so passwords are unencrypted). I seem to be able to achieve what I wanted by doing this, adding shell extensions along with the "allow locked remote desktop" extension and making the pc lock itself after getting to the desktop. The disabling of the keyring seems to be the only way for it to save... Or is there a way of getting the best of both worlds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect when Remote Desktop is on login screen or screen locked (without autologin)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411504/connect-when-remote-desktop-is-on-login-screen-or-screen-locked-without-autolog)

Comment: Also see this answer to [Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless/1409120#1409120)

Comment: I've read about the part of xrdp being unable to reconnect to a previous session by default, and that it would require some configuration before it can. There's also the part were it cant connect to a remote pc which is already logged in to a user. I will probably end up reading about xrdp some more if it allows you to keep the keyring enabled... Would there be a way to read the unencrypted passwords from the lock screen (remotely) if someone managed to get past the rdp login screen?