RDP into ubuntu vm without logged in user. i.e. display logon screen from mac
Couldn't reply/ask in the same thread so asking again if things have changed since this was last discussed a year ago.
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403943/22-04-remote-desktop-sharing-authentication-password-changes-every-reboot]
I created an ubuntu 22.04 VM on TrueNas Scale. Installed Microsoft rdp on my mac, and enabled remote desktop connection in ubuntu, disabled auto login in ubuntu so the password does not change after each reboot.
I can only remote into the VM if I am logged in to ubuntu VM [truenas provides a 'display' option from within it's GUI, so I can open that and can see the ubuntu logon screen and login from there]. This does not make sense. If I reboot the VM or NAS the next time I start the VM it is sitting at login screen and I cannot remote into it unless I use the Truenas 'display' option to login separately. I've tried xrdp, x2go and nothing seems to work like I want it to. Also tried legacy VNC, but as soon as I logout or the VM  display is locked, I get disconnected and cannot remote back into it unless I do the Truenas 'Display' hack.
any help or suggestions would be really appreciated!
thanks!
